# A really long string have to be converted to numeric form. What datatype can be used appropriately?

Tags: c#, string, int, long-integer

My program is to decode string into number and perform some operations over this number.

The below program works fine for small string. What is the better way to handle large paragraphs (as input in this case)?!

```
public static void Main()
{
    ///<summary>Encoded String- Checking divisibility</summary>
    Console.WriteLine("Enter Lowercase Latin letters ( 'a'-'i' )");
    string originalString = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
    bool chkValue = Regex.IsMatch(originalString, @"^[a-i]+$");
    if(!chkValue)
    {
        return;
    }
    char[] originalchars = originalString.ToCharArray();
    long decodedNumber=0;
    StringBuilder decoded = new StringBuilder();
    //int stringLength = originalString.Length;
    for (int i = 0; i < originalchars.Length; i++)
    {
        decoded.Append(Convert.ToInt32(originalchars[i] - 96));
    }
    Console.WriteLine(decoded);

    string decodedString = decoded.ToString();
    bool parseResult = long.TryParse(decodedString ,out decodedNumber);

    if (parseResult == true)
    {
        if (decodedNumber % 6 == 0)
            Console.WriteLine("YES");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("NO");
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Not sure what are you trying to write here, but there is the [BigInteger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx) structure if a long is not enough

Comment: Does it really work fine for small strings? Can you make this produce `100` in decodedString ?  Just writing YES or NO might be misleading.

Comment: @Steve : Thanks. `BigInteger` fixed my problem.

Comment: Please add this as an answer rather than keeping the solution in a comment. It has also the benefit to increase your reputation. :-)   @Kalyani

Answer (score 0):

As Steve mentioned, *BigInteger* fixed my problem.